# OWIN send static file for multiple routes

Tags: c#, owin, single-page-application, katana

I'm making a SPA which sits on top of ASP.Net WebAPI. I'm waiting to use HTML5 history rather than `#/` for history routing but that poses a problem for deep linking, I need to make sure `/` and `/foo/bar` all return the same HTML file (and my JS will render the right part of the SPA).

How do I get OWIN/Katana to return the same HTML file for multiple different urls?

Comment: So you want any URL hitting the server to serve index.html using static file middleware?

Comment: Yep, any route (or any route matching `/app/*`) will return the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make things simple, while still keeping all the caching goodness etc. from the StaticFiles middleware, I'd just rewrite the request path using an inline middleware, like this

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/app", spa =>
        {
            spa.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");

                return next();
            });

            spa.UseStaticFiles();
        });

        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }
}
```

This will serve the welcome page on anything but `/app/*`, which will always serve index.html instead.

Comment: This does not seem to work when you also need to serve other static files (*.css, *.js, etc...) needed for the SPA.  It returns the index.html as the response content instead.

Comment: Yeah, if you have to serve other static assets under `/app`, you need to include some condition before replacing the path. You could also include a separate `UseStaticFiles` _before_ the override. That way, it would only try to request index.html if the previous static files MW fell through.

Comment: I took your idea and added another call to `UseStaticFiles` and that seems to have done the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue using Angular js, and used a slightly different approach to resolve the issue.

We used Owin to map a route to the entry point of the SPA (index.html). This allows you to access the SPA and navigate to the different pages. However, if you ever refreshed the page you would get a 404. Essentially, AngularJS's routing and Owin/Katana's routing were stepping on each others toes.

I resolved the issue by creating a custom DelegatingHandler. This delegating handler is used whenever Owin/Katana is unable to find a route matching the request (404).

```
public class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            response.Result.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(@"index.html"));
            response.Result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            response.Result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

The snippet above returns index.html, the entry point of the SPA, when we are unable to find a page matching the request.

In order to use this delegating handler, you must add the following line to your HttpConfiguration() when starting the Owin host:

```
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomDelegatingHandler());
```

In short, I have a default route that maps to the SPA, and any unrecognized route will go through the DelegatingHandler and serve the same SPA. We do not modify the Request.Path, allowing the SPA to route the request to the proper page.

Comment: This will somewhat work but in many cases, it will be advisable to use such an implementation in production. File.ReadAllText will auto-detect the encoding (which might cause issues) and will not be as efficient as other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So do you suggest I use a solution similar to the accepted answer or is there an alternative to File.ReadAllText that is preferred?