# .NET OWIN and HTML5 History

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin, html5-history

I'm running a AngularJS SPA with a .NET Web API with OWIN middlware.  I'm trying to dynamically set the base tag based on the IIS virtual path.  This is required when using HTML5 History so that files are processed to the correct paths.

I'm using OWIN middlware to remap my HTML5 History routes back to the `index.html` page like so:

```
namespace API
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapWhen((r) => !r.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"), 
            spa =>
            {
                spa.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");
                    return next();
                });

                spa.UseStaticFiles();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With a index.html page looking like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>here</div>
    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to dynamically set the base tag like above to something like: `/mywebsite/`.  I know you could do this with a razor view very easily but it seems silly to use MVC just to set one base tag.

I was fiddling with doing something like reading the file and replace on Startup like this:

```
var index = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Web\\index.html");
var baseTag = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~");
index = index.Replace(@"<base href=""/"">", "<base href=\"" + baseTag + "\">");

app.MapWhen(r => !r.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"), spa =>
{
    spa.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(index);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        context.Response.Body = stream;
        return next();
    });

    spa.UseStaticFiles();
});
```

but I wanted to see if anyone had any better ideas.

Similar items:

- [OWIN send static file for multiple routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222062/owin-send-static-file-for-multiple-routes)
- https://github.com/goranobradovic/playwithowin
- https://github.com/Romoku/angular-subdirectory-sample